# Show that Newton’s Method is well-defined for all k and converges to 0 for $x_0>0$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $f : R → R$ with $f$ twice continuously differentiable, $\gamma > f''(x)>\delta, f(0)=0,f'(x)>\rho $  for $x ≥ 0$. Show that for any $x_0 > 0$ that Newton’s Method is well-defined for all $k$ and converges to $0$.

Where these constants are as in this theorem:
[image]

$f'\in Lip_{\gamma}(D)$ means for any $x,y \in D$, $|f'(x)-f'(y)|\leq \gamma |x-y|$.
First we notice that $x^*=0$ is the root we need the method to converge for. What I am thinking of is that since $f''(x)>\delta? 0$, that means $f$ is concave up, also $f'(x)>\rho>0$ implies $f$ is increasing and both implies $f$ is 1-1.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Hint: $|x_{n+1} - x_n| = \left|\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\right| = \left|\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_*)}{x_n-x_*}\right|\frac{1}{|f'(x_n)|}|x_{n} - x_*|$

Comment: But what about $f''(x)$ and what about the Lipschitz constant?